# qt - Actually when dragEnterEvent,dragLeaveEvent and gragMoveEvent are activated?

Tags: qt

In my program I override the dragEnterEvent but it never called, So that I want to know about when it's called?

**UPDATE**

Here the code

```
class RealBoard:public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
RealBoard();
void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
void dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
//void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
// void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};


RealBoard::RealBoard():QGraphicsScene()
{
setSceneRect(-10,-10,620,620);
}

void RealBoard::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
exit(0);
// addItem(temp);
}

void RealBoard::dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
/*
QGraphicsScene::dragLeaveEvent(event);
tempCoin->setZValue(0);
delete temp;
temp=NULL;
*/
exit(0);
}

/*
void RealBoard::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
QPointF click=event->buttonDownScenePos(Qt::LeftButton);

if(itemAt(click)!=boardP)
{
    itemAt(click)->setZValue(1);
    tempCoin=dynamic_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(itemAt(click));
   // exit(0);
    temp=new QGraphicsPixmapItem((static_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(itemAt(click))->pixmap()));
    temp->setPos(itemAt(click)->pos());
    temp->setZValue(0);
    addItem(temp);
    update(temp->pos().x(),temp->pos().y(),75,75);
}
}
*/
```

Comment: I think you have to show code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Qt 4.5.3 documentation,

**The QDragEnterEvent class provides an event which is sent to a widget when a drag and drop action enters it.**  More about `QDragEnterEvent` [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdragenterevent.html#details)

Comment: Can you please say why I the function not called in the above function.

Comment: @ prabhakaran, Your code seems to be fine for me.. Did u check by having a breakpoint at exit(0) at dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) function??

Comment: @liaK 
Ya man. Now also it is not reaching the function at all.

Comment: Try having Q_OBJECT macro in the class declaration. I am not sure whether Event handling requires Q_OBJECT macro, but give it a try though, since all the sub classes of QObject should have that macro.

Comment: @Prabhakaran: Are the items moveable? item->flags() & QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable > 0 ? Also, try dragging something from outside your application into the scene, for example an icon from your desktop.

Comment: @Robin yes, I set those flags as movable. You are correct. The function called when I tried to do so. But in my case there is no need to( and shouldn't) do that.

Comment: @liak how to declare Q_OBJECT

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem is that you have not accepted drops.
I'm not sure if `QGraphicsScene()` accepts drops but you should do it in your constructor.
So call  `setAcceptDrops(true)` and `dragEnterEvent` handler will be called.